# Making an Ajax to push email to MailChimp list but wrong url

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

Sorry for my bad english and i am newbie in Ajax.

I try to created an Ajax to push email to MailChimp list when click button subcribe but i found that the url in my Ajax was wrong.

Here the details:

My Controller:

```
    public class MailChimpController : UmbracoApiController
    {
        private static readonly MailChimpManager Manager = new MailChimpManager();

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<Member> CreateOrUpdateMember(string listID, string emailAddress)
    {
        var member = new Member
        {
            EmailAddress = emailAddress,
            Status = Status.Pending,
            EmailType = "html",
            TimestampSignup = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("s")
        };
        var result = await Manager.Members.AddOrUpdateAsync(listID, member);
        return result;     
    }
}
```

My Html:

```
 <input type="text" class="email-input">
 <button type="button" class="button-subscribe">Subscribe</button>
```

And the last one: my Ajax:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var pattern = /^[-a-z0-9~!$%^&*_=+}{\'?]+(\.[-a-z0-9~!$%^&*_=+}{\'?]+)*@@([a-z0-9_][-a-z0-9_]*(\.[-a-z0-9_]+)*\.(aero|asia|arpa|biz|com|coop|edu|gov|info|int|mil|museum|name|net|org|pro|travel|mobi|[a-z][a-z])|([0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}))(:[0-9]{1,5})?$/i;

    $("button").click(function(){
        var _emailAddress = $("input.email-input").val();
        if (_emailAddress == "" || !pattern.test(_emailAddress)) {
            message = "Email is invalid";
            alert(message)
            return false;
        }
        if (pattern.test(_emailAddress))
        {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "@Url.Action("CreateOrUpdateMember","MailChimp")",
                data: {
                    listID: "4f8083915d",
                    emailAddress: _emailAddress
                },
                encode : true,
                success: function () {
                    alert("You have successfully subscribed, please check your email to confirm !");
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert("Something wrong, you have not subscribed yet. Please do again !");
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

What i expected: the email entered in the `input` will be add to my MailChimp list.

But here the thing:

[Pls click here to see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iZOUi.png)

I did not push my email to `mailchimp` list, i pushed it in to my local so the email was not included in my Mailchimp list.

Anyone please help me about this, what i should do in changing `url` in ajax to make it work?

Thank guys.
Phong.

Answer (score 0):

The most probable reason is that you put double quotes in both sides and inside the string as well, change your url to something like this:

```
 url: '<%= Url.Action("CreateOrUpdateMember", "MailChimp") %>'
```

OR

```
url: '@Url.Action("CreateOrUpdateMember", "MailChimp")'
```

UPDATE:

If `Asp.Net` didn't create the right `url` for you, try this:

```
$.ajax
({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/MailChimp/CreateOrUpdateMember/",
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
        listID: "4f8083915d",
        emailAddress: _emailAddress
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi @Yaser Adel Mehraban.

Thanks so much for your suggestion. I will try it and reply as soon as i get home.

Comment: Hi @Yaser Adel Mehraban,

I changed like yor suggestion but the result was still the same. I think the problem here is the incorrect logic of my Ajax Url.

Do you have any idea?

Comment: Can you try the alternative @PhongNguyen